# Under Windows [Redis 64Bit] whether can be used in a production environment?

Tags: windows, redis

I use this version on my dev environment : [Redis-64](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Redis-64/) .

And I want to know if this version is suitable for the production environment?

If can use, then compared with under Linux, what need to be pay attention to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since version 3.0.3 the windows port developers abandoned the dlmalloc and began to use jemalloc as memory allocator. And the port was actually considered for production usage. The 3.0.500 build is approved for production by ms developers ([see here](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/releases)).

And there is some kind of hell so how they bypassed the unix fork to save data to disk. Microsoft developers port call it `point-in-time heap snapshot`. And this is the most controversial part when used in production:

> Redis under windows may need up to **3 times more memory** than you need in linux version. This behavior is considered normal, because swap file in the windows can easily be up to 3 times larger than the actual amount of RAM.

I think this is acceptable only if the use Redis as LRU cache or not to save data to disk at all.

At least Redis under windows is absolutely susceptible if you Redis node use lot of memory. For example - we try to use Redis for windows (v2.8, v3.0.3, v3.0.5) on server with 512 gb of memory with 2 SSD drives (each 256 gb in raid 0) used as system disk. No any limits on windows swap file. Our test emulates our production - lots of writes and saves with RDB with utilization ~60-70% of memory. And here is was lots of hands up behaviours then this node try to save snapshots - memory consumption jumps, connection freeze during saving. Such behaviour never happens undex linux on same hardware.

Comment: Thank you for your points and the analysis of the scene, I will choose suitable  I use